# Are there any apps that save backup versions of a file with one click (save, commit, etc) live while editing?

Tags: version-control, backup, versioning, revision

Just something that will save changes automatically, while i'm editing say in gedit, or notepad plus plus, or even windows text editor, etc.

I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for and svn, bzr, and Git are too complicated. One should be able to start a new project, start writing code, and that's it!

So... I'm going to create a whole new version control system that will be more amazing and simple than all the rest! Unless something already exists? Whether it be online, or a local install, whatevs.

EDIT: Ok, the above paragraph was a bit absurd now that I read it much later. I use Git now, and Git is awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many text editors will create a backup copy of the prior version when you do a save.

Of course, this is pitiful compared to an actual version control system. You should know that many VCS integrate with editors so commits are very simple quick commands.

The minor time it takes to create a repository is insignificant compared to the time it will save you during the project.

Frankly, this sounds like an argument from ignorance.

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice little Gedit plugin: http://nerdblog.pl/2009/06/01/save-and-commit-to-git-plugin-for-gedit-2-26ave/